# SparkR installation error wget: unrecognized option '--progress-bar'

Tags: apache-spark, docker, debian, sparkr

I am trying to install SparkR in a Docker container with Debian OS. The commands I input from R console is:

```
>library(devtools)
>install_github("amplab-extras/SparkR-pkg", ref="master", subdir="pkg")
```

Then the error message is as follows:

```
Downloading GitHub repo amplab-extras/SparkR-pkg@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/amplab-extras/SparkR-pkg/zipball/master
Installing SparkR
'/usr/lib/R/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet  \
  CMD INSTALL  \
  '/tmp/RtmpvjW078/devtools12119aab1c/amplab-extras-SparkR-pkg-385fbe5/pkg'  \
  --library='/usr/local/lib/R/site-library' --install-tests

installing *source* package â€˜SparkRâ€™ ...
** libs
** arch -
./sbt/sbt assembly
Attempting to fetch sbt
wget: unrecognized option '--progress-bar'
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...

Try `wget --help' for more options.
wget: unrecognized option '--progress-bar'
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...

Try `wget --help' for more options.
Our attempt to download sbt locally to sbt/sbt-launch-0.13.6.jar failed. Please install sbt manually from http://www.scala-sbt.org/
Makefile:37: recipe for target 'target/scala-2.10/sparkr-assembly-0.1.jar' failed
make: *** [target/scala-2.10/sparkr-assembly-0.1.jar] Error 255
ERROR: compilation failed for package â€˜SparkRâ€™
* removing â€˜/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/SparkRâ€™
Error: Command failed (1)
```

Does anyone meet issues similar to this or know why this happens? I have also installed SBT manually but it seems the SparkR cannot find it.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved by the new pull:

https://github.com/amplab-extras/SparkR-pkg/pull/254

It should no longer be an issue.